# How to share RelativeLayout with Scrollview and ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want to scroll the comments section,

```
<RelativeLayout...>
   <LinearLayout
          id = "@+id/holder"....>
          <ScrollView..>
               <TextView ....commetns/>
          </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
          layout_below="@id/holder.....>
     </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but the listview is not allowed to scroll the textview contents.I know the android is not allowed to use both listview and scrollview in a same viewgroup but eventhough my requirement is like this.Please help me out..........

Comment: why dont u go for header and footer with listview?

Comment: Yes you are correct if it's listview within scrollview.But here, content actually part of the activity.So I want to scroll the textview to see the details(Upto specified height) and below listview.